# How do I get random data from Socrata API?

Tags: socrata, soda

How can I get random data sample from Socrata API? Namely, I'm trying to get https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/s8d9-z734.json, but in moment do not prefer to download it whole, as it is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance and caching reasons (imagine the impact of a bunch of clients calling `$order=rand()` over and over...), we don't have any sort of `rand()` or sampling functions, but you can create your own sample set with a little bit of work:

1. Perform a `$select=count(*)` query to determine how large the set is
2. Use `rand()` locally to come up with some offsets
3. Use `$limit` and `$offset` in conjunction with a stable `$order` to pick out individual records. Ex: `$order=facility_id&$limit=1&$offset=<some rand() number>`

Unfortunately to get a sample size of 1000, that'll take 1001 calls to the API. Make sure you sign up for an [app token](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/app-tokens.html)...

Answer (score 1):

Looked for a field that could be treated like a random seed, like sorting alphabetically total_charges (i.e. random sampling of  https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/s8d9-z734.json?$limit=1000&$order=total_charges&$offset=10000) but it turns out Socrata knows this is a numerical field in spite of returning it as a string in JSON and sorts it numerically. Brighter ideas, anyone? Random sampling is an important problem in open data :-)