# Pull random sample from API in R?

Tags: r, api, random, bigdata

I have a group project for a class and we need to create a shiny app. The data we want to use is from NYC OpenData and it contains 6M records. We just want to get a random sample from it. and my original thought is to called some data and do random sample with it, but the first 900k data were only for 12/2020, 01/2021, and 02/2021. If I want to get random months while I pull from API, what can I do?

Here is my code:

```
api_tokn <- paste0("$$app_token=",key_get("NYC_NINEONEONE")) 
api_endpoint <- "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/n2zq-pubd.json?"
api_limit <- "&$limit=900000"
#api_filter <- "&borough=BRONX"
nineoneone <- slice(fromJSON(paste0(api_endpoint, api_tokn, api_limit)))
class(nineoneone)
colnames(nineoneone)
glimpse(nineoneone)
sample_n(nineoneone,10000)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568628/how-do-i-get-random-data-from-socrata-api) to get row count and random rows from a Socrata API (as used by NYC open data)

you can generate random row indices to iterate over in your API query like this:

```
row_indices <- 
  sample(1:row_count, ## total row count of API dataset
         size = desired_size, ## your desired sample size
         replace = FALSE)
```